# Sound generated not being saved to a file, as it should

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, wave

I generate a sound wave on frequency 440hz as expected in pyaudio, but even though I am using the same sample array to save a wav file, it does not save the same sound and I can´t figure out why

Here is the code:

```
import wave
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5  # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100  # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 2.0  # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
channels = 1

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)


def get_value(i):
    return np.sin(f * np.pi * float(i) / float(fs))


samples = np.array([get_value(a) for a in range(0, fs)]).astype(np.float32)

for i in range(0, int(duration)):
    stream.write(samples, fs)

wf = wave.open("test.wav", 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(3)
wf.setframerate(fs)
wf.setnframes(int(fs * duration))
wf.writeframes(samples)
wf.close()

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

https://gist.github.com/badjano/c727b20429295e2695afdbc601f2334b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you are using the `float32` data type which is not supported by the `wave` module.
You can use `int16` or `int32` or you can use 24-bit integers with some manual conversion.
Since you are using `wf.setsampwidth(3)`, I assume you want to use 24-bit data?

I've written a [little tutorial about the `wave` module](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb) (including how to handle 24-bit data) and an [overview about different modules for handling sound files](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/index.ipynb).
You may also be interested in my tutorial about [creating a simple signal](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/simple-signals.ipynb).

Since you are already using NumPy, I recommend using a library that supports NumPy arrays out-of-the-box and does all the conversions for you.
My personal preference would be to use the [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/) module, but I'm quite biased.
For playback, I would also recommend using a library that supports NumPy. Here my suggestion is the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module, but I'm very biased here as well.

If you want to follow my suggestions, your code might become something like that (including the handling of `volume` and fixing a missing factor of `2` in the sinus' argument):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

volume = 0.5  # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100  # sampling rate, Hz
duration = 2.0  # in seconds
f = 440.0  # sine frequency, Hz

t = np.arange(int(duration * fs)) / fs
samples = volume * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)

sf.write('myfile.wav', samples, fs, subtype='PCM_24')

sd.play(samples, fs)
sd.wait()
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to keep using PyAudio, that's fine.
But you'll have to manually convert the floating point array (with values from `-1.0` to `1.0`) to integers in the appropriate range, depending on the data type you want to use.
The first link I mentioned above contains the file [utility.py](https://github.com/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/utility.py) which has a function `float2pcm()` to do just that.

Here's an abbreviated version of that function:

```
def float2pcm(sig, dtype='int16'):
    i = np.iinfo(dtype)
    abs_max = 2 ** (i.bits - 1)
    offset = i.min + abs_max
    return (sig * abs_max + offset).clip(i.min, i.max).astype(dtype)
```

Comment: I don't want to use sounddevice because it is not working on windows 10, I tried changing to int32 but when I change: astype(np.float32) to astype(np.int32) I got no sound

Comment: I managed to make it work, but now I got a clicking sound with the audio https://gist.github.com/badjano/c727b20429295e2695afdbc601f2334b

Comment: I suspect the clicking sound comes from the fact that you are creating a one-second signal and play it back two times? What about using my modified code to generate the whole two-second signal at once? Also, don't forget the factor of `2`, otherwise your tone will be an octave too low.

Comment: I tested your code on my mac, it is way better and not dealing with ints insted of floats is also good... too bad it doesn't work on windows, I wanted to make something that works on the 3 major OSs

Comment: The `sounddevice` module *does* in general work on all 3 major OSs, including Windows and specifically including Windows 10. There seems to be an issue on some systems, though: https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/7.